# How to take event on Token received Authentication OpenIdConnect

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Using two type of Authentication for ASP .Net Controller and web api controller. How to take event on Token received Authentication OpenIdConnect ?

````
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
//app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try configure as below:

```
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(op =>
{
    op.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenResponseReceived = context =>
        {
            ..........
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```